# Making router into Ubuntu computer

Tags: ubuntu, router

does anyone know how to make a RT-N66U with 200mb ram and SSH access into a ubuntu computer, with external HDD (not enough internal HDD on router). I assume this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Marcus, welcome to Super User. Please explain why you'd want to run Ubuntu on a dedicated networking device or what you want to achieve. Specialized firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is much better suited if you just want Linux functionality.

Comment: Maybe to install apache, etc. It would be cool to have apt-get on it, install VNC and so on. DD-WRT has apt-get, and is possible to install on ASUS RTN66U?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu current officially supports only three architectures: x86, x86_64, and PowerPC.  These are not currently found in all but the most niche home routers, and your Asus router has a broadcom MIPS processor, so it is very unlikely that you'll be able to get Ubuntu working on that device.

However, Ubuntu isn't especially well suited to the tasks of a typical home router, so you probably be better-off with a Linux distribution like openWRT or DD-WRT which are tailored towards embedded systems and handle all the routing and media sharing tasks that are implied from your question.  This includes attaching USB hard disks and sharing media / running bittorrent etc.

For openWRT (my recommended embedded Linux OS) it appears that the RT-N66U [is not currently supported](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/asus/rt-n66u).

DD-wrt [does support the RT-N66U](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Asus) but as I use OpenWRT on my devices, I don't have experience with DD-WRT.

See the DD-WRT homepage for more information on how to get started.  They also have an excellent forum for those needing more help or information.

Comment: Okay, thanks for info, i will look more at mips OS, and maybe dd-wrt (though I already have bittorrent and download functions)

Comment: @MarcusN I'm pretty sure MIPS OS just handle the kernel, and then people like OpenWRT and Debian use that in their distributions. I'd highly recommend a fully packaged OS like DD-WRT in this case as MIPS OS just add new device support to the Linux kernel

Comment: OpenWRT is more geared towards non-router use.  Hopefully support for it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pretty powerful box.  (It seems like there's a hidden MicroSD card on the inside of it?) I see why you are interested in pursing a Linux install on it.

Looks like [there is interest in getting OpenWRT working on it](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/10852) and you may, if you are careful and your router is the correct revision, [get DD-WRT working on it (be careful, there is a risk of bricking it!)](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N66U).  I mention this because if you do not have root access you aren't getting anywhere, and either of these two methods will do that. I'd keep an eye on both those links for further developments or information.

I have never tried it, but since you have USB ports and therefore can attach some decent storage to the unit, if you do manage to get DD-WRT on it, you can try a chrooted Debian install via [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap).  Search for instructions on doing a chrooted Linux install on the Palm Pre or Android - though I bet the architecture for this unit is `mipsel`.  This is involved and not simple, but again, if you do get DD-WRT on there, it's likely possible.

Once you have the Debian chroot on there, add whatever repositories for the Ubuntu software you want to install - though to be honest, I don't think Ubuntu supports `mipsel` which is probably the CPU type that this unit is.  Things like `apache` and such are available under Debian, though, or you can compile the software you want.

To start the chroot you'd have to `ssh` in to the box and do something like `chroot -c /wherever-linux-is/bin/bash` and you'll be "in" the chroot afterward. Read more about chrooted Debian installs to understand how they work.

The only thing is is that you can't update the kernel.  You're stuck running the kernel DD-WRT boots into.  However, DD-WRT may support loading different kernels or updating the kernel it stores in flash.  I simply just don't know that much about the internals of DD-WRT.  It's a process you'd have to do yourself, the updates from Debian would not update wherever DD-WRT stores the kernel.

Of course, if you knew a lot about the internals of the Debian or Ubuntu installers, as well as the boot process of this unit - which could be gleaned through intimate knowledge of how DD-WRT does it, you could modify the "alternative" Ubuntu installers or the Debian installer to support this unit.  That's far, far beyond my current knowledge though.